# Inconsistent behavior of Setters in WPF Style Triggers in conjunction with Local Values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I am using a custom TextBox control for my WPF application, which has a default style set in a Generics.xaml file. The Template I set in the file includes the following Setter and Triggers:

`<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />`

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
</Trigger>
<MultiDataTrigger>
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsEmptyStringConverter}}" Value="False" />
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
<MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" TargetName="Border" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

If I do not set a Local Value for the Background property, this code works as expected. When focused, my Background turns to yellow and when not focused and there are no Validation errors, it turns green.

However, If I set a Local Value for the Background property, like in the following code snippet, the Background behavior is pretty strange when one of the triggers is fired.

`<custom:TextBox Background="Orange" />`

- When the IsFocued trigger is fired, the Background stays Orange. I assume that this is due to the [Dependency Property Setting Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of WPF, which favors Local Values over those set in a Style Trigger. And yes, the Trigger is definitely fired, as the BorderBrush and Foreground changes.
- When the second Trigger (MultiDataTrigger for Validation) is fired, the Background changes to Green. The Local Value is ignored.

As far as I can see this is inconsistent. Why does the first Trigger use my Local Value while the second one sticks to its Background Setter? Are there any different priorities between these two triggers?

Comment: your missing  TargetName="Border" in the isFocused trigger for the background setter so your isfocused and multidata triggers are most likely targeting different backgrounds

Comment: Thank you! When I add the attribute, the Background turns yellow when selected. Does that mean that when I target a specific Control in the Setter, the value is not overwritten by a Local Value?

Comment: basically think of it like this your textbox control is just a collection of child controls when you set the local value your setting the property of the base control when your targeting "Border" your specifying the property of a child control that overlays your base control

Answer (score 0):

**Style triggers** or **Template trigger** can't change a value set by **Local Value**
but they can change the inherited properties of the children of that control using **TemplatedParent template**

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Width="100" Height="100" Background="Pink"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the example The Button Backgound Property will stay Pink (The Local Value) you can see that using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

But if you hover over the button you will see that the background are changing that happens because the children of the button (a Border) is changed by its parent TemplatedParent and TemplatedParent.Trigger. Again use [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see the value source